# Getting error with Spring batch

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I am getting below error when I am executing my Java application :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: org.springframework.transaction.annotation.TransactionManagementConfigurationSelector was imported as a Configuration class but is not annotated with @Configuration nor does it declare any @Bean methods. Update the class to meet either of these requirements or do not attempt to import it.
Offending resource: class path resource [org/springframework/transaction/annotation/TransactionManagementConfigurationSelector.class]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitionForConfigurationClassIfNecessary(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:153)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:111)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:188)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:132)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:405)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:65)
    at org.sbq.batch.mains.SchedulerRunner.<init>(SchedulerRunner.java:46)
    at org.sbq.batch.mains.SchedulerRunner.main(SchedulerRunner.java:52)
```

I don't have any clue about this kind of exception. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mixing different versions of springbatch. Try downloading the latest version of all the jars and execute it.

Similar problem was posted by someone in the SpringSource Forum, in this [link](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?138595-Bean-Core-and-Context-library-backward-compatibilty)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using different versions of the spring and spring batch jars might produce 'offending resource' exception